# Zend framework - module based system architecture

Tags: zend-framework

Be easy on me... I'm brand new to the Zend framework!

Im trying to figure out the best way to create a CMS using Zend which is extendable with modules. These are modules for the CMS not necessarily a module for Zend. For example, there could be an event registration module, photo gallery module, etc. I want each module to define its own URIs instead of in an _initRoutes() in bootstrap.php. This allows each module to be an independent unit like they are in any CMS. The thought is that there could be a hook in a module's main controller defining URI info which is then cached in the database and used by the router.

A few specific questions:

1. Should the front controller route requests to a module 'front controller' / main controller which routes the request to a specific controller/action within the module? Basically, each module has its own front controller responsible for routing requests to controllers/actions. Is there a better structure for doing this?
2. Is there a better way than using a hook for a module to define URIs?

Again, I'm new to Zend and just trying to figure out the basics. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the front controller route requests to a module 'front controller' / main controller which routes the request to a specific controller/action within the module?

No, you should only ever have one front controller.

> Is there a better way than using a hook for a module to define URIs?

If you make each module a ZF module, you can create module-specific bootstrap classes. In each module bootstrap class you can then add an _initRoutes() method which defines the routes for that module alone.

Comment: Thats pefect!  Thanks!  How would I got about 'enabling' or 'disabling' a ZF module?  Also, how would i go about creating a table or whatever on 'install' and the opposite on 'uninstall'?

Comment: In your main bootstrap, instead of using addModuleDirectory (which will load all modules), you can add individual ones using addControllerDirectory. So you could work out which modules should be in use on the site and then loop through the list calling addControllerDirectory for each. As for install/uninstall, this depends how and where you allow additional modules to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Im new to the ZF and love it so far.